# How to stop the browser window from relocate to :target id element?

Tags: html

in this demo https://css-tricks.com/examples/Target/ when I click on a "one" number the browser window relocate to div id="one", is there any way to stop this relocate effect?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the :target selector.

Answer (score 0):

Using `event.preventDefault();`on the click event of your div element you could stop the relocation of the window.